# Error using \Glsentrytext{} in section title

Tags: latex, glossaries

When using the `glossaries` package in a LaTeX document I occasionally want to use a glossary entry as part of section or chapter title.  For example:

```
\section{\Glsentrytext{big}}
```

This however results in an error.  Trying to use `\protect\Glsentrytext{}` does not solve the the problem.  Note that using the non-capitalized version (`\glsentrytext`) does not produce any problems.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work?

I use the glossaries package occasionally as way to format specific strings in a consistent way.  For example `\gls{big}` turns into 'beam-into-gas'.  Obviously I could create two glossary entries, with and without caps, to achieve this and only include one in the final glossary.  That is an ugly solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know why this doesn't work or how to fix it but I know a workaround:

**Note:** This requires a current version of the `glossaries` package. I tested it with version 2.07 which worked and with version 2.03 which didn't work because the user1-user6 keys didn't exist in that version.

### Workaround

Define the entry with the following command:

```
\newglossaryentry{big}{name=big,type=main,text={beam-into-gas},user1={Beam-into-gas}}
```

And then use it like that:

```
\section{\glsentryuseri{big}}
```

If the section title is the only occurrence of the entry then you have to add the entry to the glossary manually using `\glsadd{big}`.

### Comment

This workaround is similar to the idea you posted about creating two entries except that you don't have to create two entries. :-)

However, I could imagine that the fact that `\Glsentrytext` doesn't work is a limitation in LaTeX which would mean that it can't be done. But this is just guessing though.

PS: Maybe you should have posted the question on http://tex.stackexchange.com to get an answer faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is definitely better that having two separate entries from a keeping track of things point of view.  I haven't actually tried it (that project is compete by now), but I'll take your word for it.